# Did X-Men Days of Future Past bring any innovation to the time travel theme?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past

*X-Men: Days of Future Past* wasn't the first with time travel theme.

Did it bring something different? What was the innovation?

Comment: “why is it considered to be a pioneer?” Is it?

Comment: Portuguese if you don't mind:
https://www.amazon.com.br/product-reviews/858368023X/ref=cm_cr_dp_see_all_btm?ie=UTF8&showViewpoints=1&sortBy=recent

Comment: This is just one example that I saw through time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It wasn't by a long shot.  The earliest writings on time travel go back to the  Mahabharata, the earliest comic I can reference is **All Star Comics** issue 10 from 1942 where:

> The Justice Society of America uses a time ray to travel 500 years into the future in order to secure an effective defense system with which to protect America against bombing attacks.

I'll leave the discussion about whether X Men DOFP was innovative to others, not my area of knowledge.

Comment: Honorable mention: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Val%C3%A9rian_and_Laureline. The series started in 1967 and had time travel as its central plot point.

Comment: As well as [*Alley Oop,*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alley_Oop) which was created in 1932 (the time-travel theme began in 1939).

Comment: All StaR Comics. Coudn't edit your answer, few characters.

Comment: Bloody autocorrect on my phone!